# check values betwwen hashmap and arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I want to realize a program that contains a `hashmap<integer,ArrayList<integer>>`and `Arraylist<integer>`

I want to test every value in arraylist if it is equal to the  arraylist hashmap  value

For example the first arraylist element with the first element in hashmap, the second arraylist element with a second element hashmap etc.

If are equal I incremete the counter and store it in a new hashmap that contains the keys and the counter

this is what i do

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> sim = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
List<Integer> listOperateur = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {
       //hmm and listOperateur Already established and filled

                    if (e.getValue().equals(listOperateur)) {
                        count++;

            }
            sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
    }


    }
```

Comment: 1. You didn't ask a question, so it isn't clear what you want to know.

2. Your code compares an empty array list with the values contained in the HashMap. This doesn't sound like what you wanted to achieve.

3. There's no real meaning in the order of HashMap entries. So comparing "the first element" with anything is meaningless.

Comment: I do not know how to do it, 
How to test the first arraylist element with the first hashmap element, the second element with the second element etc.

And if the elements compared are identical I will add 1 to the counter and store the counter in a new hashmap

Comment: Entries in HashMaps are unordered. There's no meaning for the term "first element".

Comment: The first value in  arraylist from hashmap and the first value in arraylist
the second with second etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this program that does what I need But it does not give the correct result

```
    Iterator i1 = listOperateur.iterator();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> e : hmm.entrySet()) {

            count = 0;

            for (Integer mapValue : e.getValue()) {

                if (mapValue.equals(listOperateur.get(k))) {
                    count++;

                }
            }
            sim.put(e.getKey(), count);
            k++;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap doesn't maintain order, you should prefer using **LinkedHashMap** for maintaining the order and so that you can compare as needed.

Comment: how to use LinkedHashMap ??

Comment: @fatoma Please refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140856/what-is-linkedhashmapk-v

Comment: @fatoma Can you please tell me what you gonna compare? But one thing i realize is you are trying to iterate through in order for comparing.

Comment: fr exemple hasmap H :
1   [0, 1, 1, 0]
2   [0, 1, 1, 1]
3   [1, 0, 1, 0]
arraylist 

1
1
1
1
hashmap result ( similair element sum)

1   [2]
2   [3]
3   [2]

Comment: what is this ? _(similair element sum) 1 [2] 2 [3] 3 [2]_

Comment: that is to say
1 is the key [2] is:
{1   [0, 1, 1, 0]} in hashmap and {1,1,1,1}
first element hashmap=0 first element arraylist=1 --> not similair =0|
second element hashmap=1 second element arraylist=1 -->  similair= 1|
third element hashmap=1 thirdelement arraylist=1 -->  similair=1| etc.
then count =2